# SQL find out how many users have each permission of all users who have another permission (BITWISE)

Tags: mysql, count, mariadb, bit-manipulation

So I have a table of users with their bitwise permissions in two columns. One of these columns is `permissions` and the other is `app1`

The following shows all users who have permissions to view `app1` based on the value in `permissions`. The value inside the `app1` column will determine their role in app1.

```
SELECT `authorized_users`.* FROM `authorized_users` WHERE `permissions` & (SELECT `bits` FROM `user_permissions` WHERE `permission_name` = 'app1' AND `app` = 'global')
```

I need to see how many people have each role in `app1`. All of them must have permisson to access `app1`. This is once again determined by the value in the `permissions` column, the value they must have can be found using:

```
SELECT `bits` FROM `user_permissions` WHERE `permission_name` = 'app1' AND `app` = 'global'
```

I would like results with columns such as:
`supplier`, `client`, `consultant` each showing how many people have each role. A user can have multiple roles, hence the use of BITWISE

`user_permissions` looks like this:
[image: user_permissions table]

Any and all help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts and desired output for this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `LEFT` join of `user_permissions` to `authorized_users` and aggregation:

```
SELECT p.permission_name, COUNT(u.permissions) counter
FROM user_permissions p LEFT JOIN authorized_users u
ON u.permissions & p.bits
WHERE p.app = 'app1'
GROUP BY p.permission_name
```